# DataBindingUtil.setContentView | Not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

When i use view binding it works fine but when i use data binding i receive errors

My Imports :

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.shoestore.R
import com.example.shoestore.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
```

My code :

```
   val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

Error message :

```
Not enough information to infer type variable T
```

gradle :

```
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

- I tried to disable view binding thought that it conflict with data binding generated classes
- I tried the android studio auto complete thought that i typed it wrong and the auto complete was expecting type of  ViewDataBinding!

```
    val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

error message for this code :

```
Type expected
```

- tried to smart cast and it worked but i cant access the views only the root

```
val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) as ViewDataBinding
```

Comment: How about specifying to activity main binding `val binding: ActivityMainBinding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) `?; or casting to that `val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) as ActivityMainBinding`?

Comment: enabling both only proves that you have no idea what those are, if you want to use binding variables and also do stuff like two way bindings use dataBinding, if you only wish to use binding variables, use viewBinding only (viewBinding is "a part" of dataBinding)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this. In Your Activity or Fragment

- set `ContentView` In Fragment

  ```
   private var binding1: FragmentAddItemBinding? = null
   private val binding get() = binding1!!

   override fun onCreateView(
   inflater: LayoutInflater,
   container: ViewGroup?,
   savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
   binding1 = FragmentAddItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

   //Here is your code

   return binding.root
  }
  ```
- set `ContentView` In the Activity

  ```
  private var binding : ActivityMainBinding? = null


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding!!.root)

   //Your Code is here 

   }
  ```

It's Work for me so I just hope this work for you

Comment: Thats work but not what im looking for 

The purpose is that i want to use DataBindingUtils instead of view binding

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention the type of variable binding like this:

```
val binding : ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

instead of

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

This should solve the issue

Comment: Sadly : Type mismatch: inferred type is ViewDataBinding! but ActivityMainBinding was expected

Comment: Have you converted your xml file 1st or not ?

Comment: i suggest you follow this codelab : https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-databinding#2

Comment: dataBinding {enabled = true}

instead of 
buildFeatures {databinding = enabled }

solved it and idk how